# HTML <p> nodes InnerText including anchor text in CsQuery

Tags: csquery

I'm parsing some wordpress blog articles using CsQuery to do some text clustering analysis on them. I'd like to strip out the text from the pertinent `<p>` node.

```
var content = dom["div.entry-content>p"];
if (content.Length == 1)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content[0].InnerHTML);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content[0].InnerText);
}
```

In one of the posts the `InnerHTML` looks like this:

```
An MIT Europe project that attempts to <a title="Wired News: Gizmo Puts Cards 
on the Table" href="http://www.wired.com/news/technology/0,1282,61265,00.html?
tw=rss.TEK">connect two loved ones seperated by distance</a> through the use 
of two tables, a bunch of RFID tags and a couple of projectors.
```

and the corresponding `InnerText` like this

> An MIT Europe project that attempts to  through the use of two tables,
>   a bunch of RFID tags and a couple of projectors.

i.e. the inner text is missing the anchor text. I could parse the HTML myself but I am hoping there is a way to have CsQuery give me

> An MIT Europe project that attempts to *connect two loved ones
>   seperated by distance* through the use of two tables, a bunch of RFID
>   tags and a couple of projectors.

(my italics.) How should I get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   string result = dom["div.entry-content>p"].Text();
```

Text function will include everything that is bellow p includes p tag.

Comment: Does it really?  I'm finding it does not https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/issues/186

Comment: Yes, element should wrap in CQ.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

```
using HAP = HtmlAgilityPack;
...
var doc = new HAP.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("Your html");
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"node xPath");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText());
```

xPath is the path to the node on the page.

For example: In Google Chrome, press F12 and select your node, right-click and select "Copy xPath"

This topic header xPath: //*[@id="question-header"]/h1/a

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the xpath equivalent of the CsQuery call `dom["div.entry-content>p"]` is? I'm getting an exception from the HtmlAgilityPack with `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div.entry-content>p")`

Comment: Excellent - all works. I had to change `node.InnerText()` to `node.InnerText` and `dom["div.entry-content>p"]` became `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='entry-content']//p")`

Comment: I'll leave this for a bit before marking it as the answer just-in-case there is a way to achieve the same in CsQuery